# Show that $f(x)=a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{0}$ is $\Theta(x^n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that $f(x)=a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{0}$ is $\Theta(x^n)$.

In an attempt to show the lower bound $\Omega(x^n)$, I got stuck at the following assuming $k_{1}= 1$:
$$\mid f(x) \mid=\mid a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{0}\mid$$
$$\ge \mid k_{1}x^n+k_{1}x^{n-1}+...+k_{1}\mid$$
$$\ge \mid k_{1}(x^n+x^{n-1}+...+1)\mid$$
$$\ge \mid k_{1}(x^n)\mid$$

**Question**:why $\mid a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{0}\mid  \ge  \mid k_{1}x^n+k_{1}x^{n-1}+...+k_{1}\mid$ as $a_{n}, a_{n-1}, ...$ could be larger numbers than $k_{1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just observe that
$$\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=a_n+a_{n-1}x^{-1}+\cdots +a_0x^{-n} $$
and the limit of the right hand side is $a_n\ne0$.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't get how that relates as to why we replaced $a's$ with $k_{1}$